# Project equirectangular image to a plane correctly

Tags: shaders, vector-mapping

I have a large equirectangular colour image of the earth. I was wondering if there's an easy or fairly correct way to project it so that a section of it correctly renders on a flat plane?

Colour image: [earth-color_21K.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1rxblwi19i78ieh/AADNsHNRA7SysJ015GkXplewa?dl=0) (from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YZzHn0iz8U) about spherical earth models)

This isn't meant as a discussion about appropriate projection methods for maps. I'm asking what methods there are within Blender for re-projecting from a section of a sphere onto a flat plane. (I'd rather not use QGIS if I don't have to). Apologies if this has already been answered - I couldn't find it

Many thanks

Comment: as your image is already flat, why would you need to project it from a sphere to a plane?

Comment: Because it is distorted.  I'd like a mercator-style map projection, or something similar.